# jsonschema2pojo generating objects of custom annotators as well

Tags: java, annotations, jsonschema, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I'm generating pojo using jsonschema2pojo maven plugin. Using custom annotator, I'm including some lombok annotations (which works fine) but it also creates variables for annotations. Is there a way to force jsonschema2pojo to not create object variables for annotation and simply just have variables?

json schema

```
{
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "lombok-builder": true,
    "lombok-data": true,
    "lombok-to-string": true,
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

custom annotator

```
 @Override
    public void propertyField(JFieldVar field, JDefinedClass clazz, String property, JsonNode propertyNode) {
        super.propertyField(field, clazz, property, propertyNode);

        if (property.equals("lombok-builder")) {
            clazz.annotate(Builder.class);
        } else if (property.equals("lombok-data")) {
            clazz.annotate(Data.class);
        } else if (property.equals("lombok-to-string")) {
            clazz.annotate(ToString.class);
        }
}
```

Person.java generated by jsonschema2pojo

```
package com.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;


/**
 * Person
 * <p>
 * 
 * 
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "lombok-builder",
    "lombok-getter",
    "lombok-setter",
    "lombok-data",
    "lombok-equals-and-hash-code",
    "lombok-no-args-constructor",
    "lombok-all-args-constructor",
    "lombok-to-string",
    "name"
})
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty("lombok-builder")
    public Object lombokBuilder;
    @JsonProperty("lombok-data")
    public Object lombokData;
    @JsonProperty("lombok-to-string")
    public Object lombokToString;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

}
```

As you can see the annotations work fine but I'm getting `public Object lombokToString;`, `@JsonProperty("lombok-to-string")` etc. :|

Answer (score 2):

After some time and research I realised I was going about it in a wrong way.
Needed to work on `propertyInclusion` with `additionalProperties`
Below is the working annotator and example schema for anyone having similar issue.

```
import com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import lombok.*;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.AbstractAnnotator;

public class LombokAnnotator extends AbstractAnnotator {

    @Override
    public void propertyInclusion(JDefinedClass clazz, JsonNode schema) {

        JsonNode additionalProperties = schema.get("additionalProperties");

        try {
            additionalProperties.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(property -> {
                Class annotation = getAnnotation(property);
                if (!annotation.equals(IllegalArgumentException.class)) {
                    clazz.annotate(annotation);
                }
            });
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("No additionalProperties defined for %s.", clazz.fullName()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAdditionalPropertiesSupported() {
        return false;
    }
```

and updated json schema

```
{
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "lombok-builder": true,
    "lombok-data": true,
    "lombok-getter": true,
    "lombok-setter": true,
    "lombok-equals-and-hash-code": true,
    "lombok-no-args-constructor": true,
    "lombok-all-args-constructor": true,
    "lombok-to-string": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share a little more on how this is implemented?  Is the annotator class you show added to the plugin?  Where does the schema file go?

Comment: Where did you put your custom annotator? Can you show the package? Mine isn't unable to load.. Is your's outside of this specific project (i.e. in a different module or jar)?